MacOS - How to assign CMD key to Pan shortcuts?
Just trying to assign more familiar shortcuts for viewport panning that work better on a MacBook without a three button mouse.
Using the Macbook's trackpad, I can assign...

OPT + SHIFT + CLICK = Pan

But I can't seem to assign...

CMD + OPT + CLICK = Pan

Does anyone know how to assign CMD + OPT instead?
Cheers, Ben

It turns out you can assign the Command key, the problem is that the Command key icon doesn't display in the keymap, even if you make the window wider. So, it displays as OPT + Click instead of CMD + OPT + Click...

Also, I'll need to test this with a mouse, but when using a MacBook trackpad, it displays as the Middle Mouse button even though it should be the Left Mouse button.
